# What datatype is an enum constant in Java?

Tags: java, enums

Given an emum like this

```
public class Main {
  enum Level {
    LOW,
    MEDIUM,
    HIGH
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Level myVar = Level.MEDIUM; 
    System.out.println(myVar);
  }
}
```

the value printed out is MEDIUM, what is it's datatype?

Comment: Its class is `[Main.]Level`, if you mean this by "*datatype*".

Comment: This makes sense. I tried to do ```System.out.println(myVar+1);``` and i got the error ```Main.java:10: error: bad operand types for binary operator '+'
    System.out.println(myVar+1); 
                            ^
  first type:  Level
  second type: int
1 error```

Comment: Enum values in Java are not integers; they're objects.

Comment: `Enum`s are just classes with some restrictions, nothing else. Thus, an `Enum`-value is not convertible to `int` or `Integer`. Therefore, infix operator `+ `is not defined for `(Enum, int)`.

Comment: `enum Foo{ X; }` is just syntactic sugar for `public class Foo extends Enum<Foo>{ public static final Foo X = new Foo(); /*plus some other methods like values(), ordinal(), name(), etc...*/}` so in case of `MEDIUM` it is `public static final Level MEDIUM = new Level();` meaning that `MEDIUM` constant holds object of type `Level` (*enum* type).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enums in Java are classes that `extend java.lang.Enum<E>`

Type of "myVar" is a class `Main.Level` which `extends java.lang.Enum<Main.Level>`

From official Java tutorial:

> Note: All enums implicitly extend java.lang.Enum. Because a class can only extend one parent (see Declaring Classes), the Java language does not support multiple inheritance of state (see Multiple Inheritance of State, Implementation, and Type), and therefore an enum cannot extend anything else.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

Answer (score 2):

An `enum`s in Java is its own type. Here, the `Level` enum is nested inside `Main`, so the type would be `Main$Level`.

Comment: The canonical name is actually `Main.Level`.